# XML problem for views in Lotus Domino

Tags: xml, lotus-domino

I'm taking over a system written for Lotus Domino on web, but I'll not familiar to this.
The view on web changes when I'm opening a category other categories dissappear. Later they re-appear when I open or closes a category...

Have anyone been experiencing this, and how can I solve it?

Brg,
Marianne

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you may be seeing is a simple display issue. By default, the Domino server is set to display 30 rows in a view, before paging is required (assuming you have a paging mechanism in your application). When you open a category in a categorised view, if that category has more than 30 entries then you need to page through to see the rest of the view effectively.

The server default can be changed on a per-site basis, but you can also change how many entries are displayed in a view by manipulating either the Domino URL or the `$$ViewTemplate` form you use to render the view (BTW, I'm assuming you're using classic Domino development rather than the newer XPages technology).

Say you want to open the view "SomeView" and display 250 rows: you would use the `count` parameter like so:

```
path_to_your_db.nsf/SomeView?OpenView&Count=250
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will investigate! Hopefully this is everything I need. I appreciate it! THANKS!